# Terraform: The given value is not valid for variable "backup_configuration": attribute "backup_retention_settings" is required

Tags: postgresql, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-template-file

I am trying to configure the automated backup retention period of **PostgreSQL** using the terraform. But i am unable to pass the value for the `backup_retention_settings`, No matter what value i provide, i get the error.

> Error: Invalid value for input variable
>
> on terraform.tfvars line 3:    3:      backup_configuration = {
> 4:     enabled                        = true    5:     start_time
> = "20:00"    6:     location                       = null    7:     point_in_time_recovery_enabled = false    8:    9:   }
>
> The given value is not valid for variable "backup_configuration":
> attribute "backup_retention_settings" is required.

Here is code for my Main.tf

```
dynamic "backup_configuration" {
      for_each = [var.backup_configuration]
      content {
        binary_log_enabled             = false
        enabled                        = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "enabled", null)
        start_time                     = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "start_time", null)
        location                       = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "location", null)
        point_in_time_recovery_enabled = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "point_in_time_recovery_enabled", false)
        backup_retention_settings      = lookup(backup_configuration.value, "backup_retention_settings", null)
      }
    }
```

from varaiables.tf

```
variable "backup_configuration" {
  description = "The backup_configuration settings subblock for the database setings"
  type = object({
    enabled                        = bool
    start_time                     = string
    location                       = string
    point_in_time_recovery_enabled = bool
     backup_retention_settings = object({
      retained_backups = string
      retention_unit   = string
    })
  })
  default = {
    enabled                        = false
    start_time                     = null
    location                       = null
    point_in_time_recovery_enabled = false
    backup_retention_settings =  {
       retained_backups = "10"
      retention_unit   = "10"
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please help me, how can i pass the values to the retention settings.

Here is the terraform template i used. https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-sql-db/pull/203/commits/d6082b691742af62b217ae200bbc18895cc6dac0

Answer (score 0):

[point_in_time_recovery_enabled](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#point_in_time_recovery_enabled) is **only for PostgreSQL**:

> (Optional) True if Point-in-time recovery is enabled. Will restart database if enabled after instance creation. **Valid only for PostgreSQL instances**.

Comment: Yes, Sorry i forget to mentioned. I ma using the PostgreSQL. do you know how to use these parameters?